# Thread-safety of java HashSet in an apache tomcat servlet

Tags: java, string, multithreading, tomcat, hashset

I'm trying to write a multi-threaded apache tomcat servlet which will receive large quantities of text in each POST body it processes and upon a GET request, it will return the number of unique words received. I have managed to accomplish this using Qt and the QtWebApp library, however I cannot seem to accomplish this in Java. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but presumably something with overall thread-safety of the application (or with how the words are being split and saved). The count of words returned is always too high (about 2000-4000 higher than the actual amount, which is 70000 to 140000 - I do have the results for these testcases). My code is below:

```
@WebServlet(name = "data", urlPatterns =     {"/myserver/","/myserver/data","/myserver/count"})
public class data extends HttpServlet {

HashSet<String> slova = new HashSet<>();
public final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");


    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {


        if("POST".equals(request.getMethod()) && "/osp/myserver/data".equals(request.getRequestURI())){

        InputStream body = request.getInputStream();
        GZIPInputStream gstream = new GZIPInputStream(body);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gstream, "UTF8"));


        String vse ="";
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();

        while ((vse = buffreader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sbuffer.append(vse);
        }

        String text = sbuffer.toString();
        System.out.println(text);


            String[] words = text.split("\\s+");

            lock.lock();
            for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){

                slova.add(words[i]);

            }
            lock.unlock();

        }
        if("GET".equals(request.getMethod()) && "/osp/myserver/count".equals(request.getRequestURI())){

            out.println(slova.size());
            slova.clear();
        }

    }
}
```

Any idea what could be causing this? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. I can post the working Qt source upon request.

Comment: Your "GET" method handling uses the collection but doesn't acquire the lock.  That is likely a problem.  None of the built-in Java collections are thread-safe unless they are specifically documented as such.

Comment: I would expect the inverse: your method should return less than the number of words, since you append lines without inserting a space between them, thus concatenating all the end-of-line words with the first word of the next line. Why don't you split each line, rather than creating a huge string in memory and then split that huge line? With that many words, my guess is that you simply didn't count correctly. Just use a small sample to test that the code works as expected (after you made it thread-safe)

Comment: Thanks for the input. The GET method is only received once, at the end of the test case. While you are correct, any error caused by thread unsafety of it would cause the return value to be less, not more.

Comment: As for the second comment - I will attempt to change the parsing like you said and report back - this is likely the case. The test case results i have are correct, i'm 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

The string splitting mentioned by JB Nizet was the root of the issue.